# How do I create a soap client?

Tags: php, soap-client

I need to create a SOAP client. The SOAP client should access services
exposed using SOAP messages. It performs dynamic bindings and executes methods at remote
web services. Soap methods are:

- getTodoList(acronym) -> List of TodoData()
- getTodoOneDay(acronym, date) -> List of TodoData()
- createTodo(acronym, time, note, priority) -> String
- updateTodo(id, acronym, time, note, priority) -> String
- deleteTodo(acronym, id) -> String

There is a soap server running on http://lol.comlab.bth.se:8090.
Please help me by giving code in either php, java, python or any other language.

Answer (score 2):

You could invoke method `getTodoList(acronym)` using **PHP SOAP Extension** in **WSDL Mode**:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://lol.comlab.bth.se:8090/PathToYour.wsdl");
$return = $client->getTodoList(acronym));
```

Or in **non-WSDL Mode**:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'location' => "http://lol.comlab.bth.se:8090/PathToYourServer.php",
    'uri'      => "urn://lol.comlab.bth.se",
    'trace'    => 1 ));

$return = $client->__soapCall("getTodoList", array(acronym));
```

Also, these tutorials could be helpful:

- [PHP SOAP Extension](http://www.herongyang.com/PHP/php_soap.html)
- [PHP SOAP Extension - Server Applications](http://www.herongyang.com/PHP/php_soap_server.html)

Comment: @JasonMichael If you have an additional information you could provide it to help him

Answer (score 1):

Just install the python-zsi library, or any other source code generator, and execute:

`wsdl2py http://lol.comlab.bth.se:8090/wsdl`

your done

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking someone to write the whole client, and not just help out with it. You might try another site to hire a coder for this.

Comment: A question like this on StackOverflow is likely to get code written in Brainfuck... especially given "Please help me by giving code in either php, java, python or **any other language**"